# jsp registration page

Tags: java, html, database, jsp

i am trying to create a register page, i don't get any error, but when i submit the results.
my database doesn't show me the new users. i think something is wrong with the executeUpdate

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import ="javax.sql.*" %>
 <%
 String username=request.getParameter("username"); 
   session.putValue("username",username); 
   String password=request.getParameter("password");
   session.putValue("username",username);

  try{
  int sqlport = 3306;
      String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
       String user = "admin";
  String pswd = "admin";
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pswd);
   Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

   ResultSet results;

   int i=stmt.executeUpdate("insert into users values ('"+username+"','"+password+"')");
 }
    catch(Exception e){
            System.out.print(e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                            }
     %>

    <html>
   <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/styles.css" />
     <body>
   <form action="register.jsp" method="POST">
      <br>Email :<input type="text" name="email" /></br>
  <br>First name :<input type="text" name="fname" /><br>
      <br>Last name :<input type="text" name="lname" /><br>
        <br>User name :<input type="text" name="username" /><br>
      <br>password :<input type="password" name="password" /></br>
      <input type="submit" value="continue">
     </form>
      </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: Ew. Also, SQL injection. Anything in the log?

Answer (score 1):

With a quick look, i see u didn't add the database name to your URL !!
you may check the link below, it is very simple and looks a lot like what you are doing.

http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/prepared-statement-query.shtml